# Unable to push the input data into my Firebase database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on the Sign Up module for our project and it's the first time I program using firebase as a backend. here's the code for my Sign Up form in HTML:

```
<form class="innerContent">
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="tName">
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tName">Name of Tailor/Tailor Shop</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="tAddress">
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tAddress">Address of Tailor/Tailor Shop</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "3" id="tDesc"></textarea>
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tDesc">Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "3" id="tContact"></textarea>
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tContact">Contact Details</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="tUsername">
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tUsername">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="tPassword">
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tPassword">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTxt mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="tRePassword">
        <label class="inputLabel mdl-textfield__label" for="tRePassword">Re-type Password</label>
    </div>
    <p>
    <input id="TaC" type="checkbox" for="TaC"> I have read the the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
    <button id="SignUpBtn" class="farBtn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect" type="button" onclick="signUp()" disabled>
        <i class="material-icons">done_all</i> Sign Up
    </button>
    </p>
</form>
```

I want a user to register all of its information into my firebase database. When the Sign Up button is pressed, it will trigger this function in my javascript:

```
function signUp(){
var name = $("#tName").val();
var address = $("#tAddress").val();
var description = $("#tDesc").val();
var contact = $("#tContact").val();
var username = $("#tUsername").val();
var pword = $("#tPassword").val();

var tailors = notsDB.child("tailors");

tailors.push({
    tName: name,
    tAddreass: address,
    tDescription: description,
    tContact: contact,
    tUsername: username,
    tPassword: pword
});
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work! I looked at my database in the firebase console and nothing's change. I tried changing the rules by replacing the `auth != null` to `true` , but it didn't work.

Setting aside the possibility of not implementing the push function properly, I'm suspecting that I'M NOT CONNECTED PROPERLY TO MY FIREBASE ACCOUNT. I recalled all the procedures I did in connecting my web app to firebase:

1. I created an account in firebase
2. I installed Node.js in my pc
3. I put the following snippet of code in my HTML file (at the bottom of the body section, before all other javascript)

```html
<!-- FIREBASE -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script>
<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCM6Ublqz7PLkRgkzGe6vhsvb7iU0BU5Tk",
    authDomain: "nots-eece8.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://nots-eece8.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "nots-eece8",
    storageBucket: "nots-eece8.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "472888671312"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Is there any procedure that I skipped in setting up the firebase in my web app? Is it necessary to install the Firebase SDK with the `npm install firebase --save`? Or the error lies in my push function?

NOTE: I've put the following code before my signUp method in my javascript file:

`var firebase = require('firebase');`

`var notsDB = new Firebase('https://nots-eece8.firebaseio.com');`

Comment: @editor who tried to remove the API key: this is just configuration data. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref.push() only return another reference, it doesn't update, you have to grab the new reference key and then update in the parent level, here's example from firebase.

```html
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
  // A post entry.
  var postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

[read and write data to firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: woah, It worked. Did I misunderstood the tutorials that I saw on the internet? I always thought that the push() method can write data into my database

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize  your firebase app using *firebase.initializeApp(config)*, this will return a reference of your app which you can use later to connect with to firebase database.

```
var fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Make use of the firebase reference stored on **fb** to connect to firebase db , You can use

```
fb.database()
```

If you want to store your signup data the you can use firebase [push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) method.

```
fb.database().ref('tailors').push({
        tName: name,
        tAddreass: address,
        tDescription: description,
        tContact: contact,
        tUsername: username,
        tPassword: pword });
```

This will create a child named *tailors* in your firebase database and store your signup data corresponding to an push Id.

Comment: Did you get any error? I guess you got firebase error _default app already exist._